# iPhone app crashes while checking internet connectivity

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, reachability

In my iPhone app, I need to detect the internet Connection availability.

So I am referencing some files from "Reachability" project of Apple.

Link is given below:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html

I create a new project and implement the code below in viewWillAppear but the app crashes.

I included the Reachability.h, Reachability.m from Apple's demo project.

I also included SystemConfiguration Framework.

app works fine when Internet is Working. But app Crashes when Internet in not Working.

Even I checked the console but there is no notification or error shown in the console.

```
   Reachability *r = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"www.google.com"];

NetworkStatus internetStatus = [r currentReachabilityStatus];
if ((internetStatus == ReachableViaWiFi) || (internetStatus == ReachableViaWWAN))
{
    UIAlertView *myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Internet Connection" message:@"Available" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [myAlert show];
    [myAlert release];
    }
else
{
    UIAlertView *myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Internet Connection" message:@"This app require an internet connection via WiFi or cellular network to work." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [myAlert show];
    [myAlert release];
    }
```

What could be the reason for crash?

What should I do?

Thanks!!

Comment: did you checked console, to check the reason for crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it may be the case that your code does not work on simulator because of time out. But try running it on device. Also try debugging the code as @greg rightly said. For that credit should go to @greg. Hope this helps. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot Julia for your input. It looks as if it is a timeout issue on simulator. That was a good observation. :)

Answer (score 4):

You're over-releasing the alerts. First, you do `autorelease` and then additionally `release`, which is too much. Just remove the two `[myAlert release];` and it should work.

Comment: I tried that but still doesnt work. It still crashes.What should I do?

Comment: I have removed that but still it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is elsewhere in your code, as the code you provided along with copying Reachability.[mh] into a fresh Xcode project seems to work without crashing.  When your app crashes, it *must* have some sort of information logged in the console.  If there truly is nothing, set a breakpoint in your "startup" methods (`viewWillLoad`, `viewDidLoad`, `AppDelegate` stuff and step through line-by-line until you catch the problem.

Comment: Hi Greg, I tried debugging.While i test on simulator with debugging it works fine but as soon as i remove breakpoints and run normally then it again crashes. So seems like a timeout issue. As Julia said it worked fine when i tested the same code on the device so it looks like time out issue on simulator. Thanks for your great help anyways!! :) :)